# Excel VBA Code to check a value each cell in column then recalculate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a set of Prices, I need to randomly assign margins to them but they all have to be lower then .88 % of List ...

Trying to write code that will go through and check every cell in a column if any of the values are > .88 then Excel will do a 'Calculate' and it will check again to see if any cells are > .88 until all cells in column are below .88

I've tried this code it goes through each cell and does a calculate but isn't checking to see if cells are > .88

`

```
 Sheets("Line Breakout Revised").Select


 For i = 1 To Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Cells(i, 1).Value > 0.88 Then Calculate

Next i





End Sub
```

Comment: What data types are the Cells set to? You can try wrapping those values in a `Cdec` first to make sure you have valid data to compare.

Comment: What are the formulas in column **U**??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a do loop using MAX():

```
Dim i As Long
i = 0
Dim Threshold As Long
Threshold = 1000
With Worksheets("Line Breakout Revised")
    Do
        .Calculate
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range(.Cells(1, "U"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp))) <= 0.88 _
        Or i >= Threshold
End With
If i >= Threshold Then MsgBox "Threshold met before accomplishing goal"
```

I put a counter in to make sure a indefinite loop does not occur.  It will loop till all the numbers are lower or equal to `.88` ***OR*** the loop has gone 1000 times.  You can adjust the threshold